GeometryNodes: computed custom "angle" attribute and how to use it in a driver
This is my second question in the forum.
I'd rather ask instead of just waiting, though i think this might be something to fix or even, maybe logic that is not yet intended.
I ll explain: i have a GeometryNodes modifier that computes and stores the angle between two vectors.
This attribute is output in the Output Group.
Then, all i do is left click in the property name and select "copy data path/copy full data path", and then perform a paste into the driver of a "Follow Path" constraint. The key to the question is that, this angle between vectors varies over the frame range and thus, the driver should be updated with different values.
Well, it doesnt work.
Is this perhaps a bug? (im using Blender 4.1.1), or rather, a logic not intended? Am i doing something wrong?


yeah, i think that would work. Only thing is, i would preferably not start by "baking" anything, since i pretend to reuse this GN camera rig "dynamically", this is, being exportable and reusable for "any kind of" Curve. Your approach would work only for one curve. If I change the curve i would still need to "rebake" again. I would rather prefer to avoid this and any kind of precomputation that assumes the curve is fixed.

@Xana the "baking" process is not a problem for me. I already got precomputed data as a "storedNameAttribute". But i would like to access this custom field/attribute value by means of a driver. And it s not helping. Nevertheless, i am hitching my head a bit about your "rotational difference" use in the driver. I guess i could map my attribute's value to an empty and use another empty, leaving it "static".

@Xana why dont you reply directly to this message, instead of here in the comments? just write and answer as a new post to this thread.

I need some clarification to understand your question. What I understand: (1) you have a closed curve. (2) you are computing a vector per point of this curve, and this angle is stored in a named attribute, and it is also output by the GN modifier. (3) the value of those angles (one per point) is changing with the frame count. What I do not understand: How this local and changing angle is used in a "Follow Path" constraint ? The provided screen capture does not show this part.

I managed to sort it out.
In order to be able to use a "precomputed" value you need first to store it with a "StoredNameAttribute".
But this, has to be stored in a Mesh Shape/Transform object, not a Curve one like i was doing.
So, what i finally did is create a "dummy" Mesh cube which i would switch off the visibility but retrieve a NodeGroup from the GN of the Curve and use it in a new GN attached to the Cube. And then perform a "StoreNamedAttribute" in the Cube Mesh.
From there on, i would create the following function as a driver:
import bpy

def get_angle_between_vectors(ev_dag):
    readable_object = bpy.data.objects["ReadComputedAngleTransform"]
    readable_object.update_tag()
    evaluated_object = readable_object.evaluated_get(ev_dag)
    angle_between_vectors = evaluated_object.data.attributes["AngleBetweenVectors"].data[0].value


bpy.app.driver_namespace['get_angle'] = get_angle_between_vectors

Note as well that the depsgraph is not evaluated inside the driver function, but rather passed on as an input parameter. The former would make blender freeze due to probably a cyclic evaluation of the graph.
Here is the snapshot of my driver configuration:

